# When updating headers with macro it only fills center header

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro to fill excel header with metadata from M-files. ( it is the only way to do it), but when I run the macro it only fills center header. Left and right headers are empty, even though I have data to put it.

Also, is there a nicer way to write this piece of code?

```
Sub AddHeaderToAll_FromMETADATASheet()
        'Add header to all worksheets
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ' Emtpy headers
                               ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = ""
                                ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ""
                                ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = ""
                                ws.PageSetup.LeftFooter = ""
            ' Fill headers and add style them.

                                ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&8&""Arial Narrow""" & Worksheets("METADATA").Range("B24").Value
                                ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&8&""Arial Narrow""" & Worksheets("METADATA").Range("B25").Value
                                ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&8&""Arial Narrow""" & Worksheets("METADATA").Range("B26").Value
                                ws.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&8&""Arial Narrow""" & Worksheets("METADATA").Range("B27").Value
        Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works if you try to put something else in them, So the problem is in the data that is being pulled from `MetaData`

Comment: Same opinion as Mikku. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested the following code and it works fine on my workbook. I suspect the reason why nothing shows up in your version, when you think it should, has to do with the information in the cells refrenced or the cell refrence itself. Are the refrences correct?

Try this in order to test the code. Note I shortend it. There is no need to empty the headers if you are overwriting the content:

**Update:** A full refrence to the calling workbook was added to the example. Please see my comment bellow on this topic as well.

```
Sub AddHeaderToAll_FromMETADATASheet()

    'Add header to all worksheets
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'Or whatever workbook contains the data
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Fill headers and add style them.
            ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&8&""Arial Narrow""" & wb.Sheet2.Range("A1").Value
            ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&8&""Arial Narrow""" & wb.Sheets.Range("A2").Value
            ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&8&""Arial Narrow""" & wb.Sheet2.Range("A3").Value
            ws.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&8&""Arial Narrow""" & wb.Sheet2.Range("A4").Value
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have tested the code and yes it works just fine. But when I want to pull data from the other cells it does not work. Do you have any idea why would that be? Could it be that the text is too long? I have to combine different cell values into one cell, to be able to fill it in the header.

Comment: If the string length is an issue, that would be easy to test for. Use Len() and see if any cell's value is longer than 32767 characters it would be, but that is pretty long. Do your cells have unhandled errors in them? A vlookup that returns NV# perhaps?

Comment: One more thought... is the data coming from the same workbook? In other words, is `Worksheets("METADATA")` in the same workbook that you are writing to? Because I just noticed that you are not fully refrencing the that worksheet object.

Comment: Yes, it is in the same workbook. I am not? what do you mean?

Comment: `Worksheets("METADATA")` is not fully refrenced. Essentially what that means is, that when Excel executes your code, it makes an assumption about what workbook this worksheet is in. If it is not fully refrenced, the assumption is that it is in the `ActiveWorkbook`. If your code jumps around and activates different workbooks, then it might be trying to pull data from the wrong one!

Comment: Hi @rohrl77. Thanks for the comments. I still wasn't able to make the macro work. It is weird. If I try to fill only LeftHeader everything is okay. But if I want to fill Left and Center Header. My left header is empty. And I have no idea why I am struggling to fix that.